# Как правильно использовать Tag-хелперы форм?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Есть небольшая форма:

```
@model IEnumerable<Store.Web.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel>

<h2>Create Customer</h2>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Customer">

        <div class="form-group">

            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" 
        />
        </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как правильно определить Name в указанном lable ?

> label asp-for="Name"

,
но появляется ошибка:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for
>   'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found

Comment: Попробуйте так `@model Store.Web.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel`

Comment: Так как это PartialView при использовании @model Store.Web.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel вылетает ошибка. Я подробно указал всё в статье. https://toster.ru/q/622344 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673172/error-creating-renderpartialasync-problem-in-controller

Comment: Вы передаете список объектов, и пытаетесь работать как с единичным объектом. Из-за этого и вылетает ошибка `IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Name'`. Проблема не в tag хелперах, а в вашей модели. Если вы хотите работать со списком, нужно пройтись по нему циклом `@foreach (var item in Model){
}`